# How to create the same whatsapp slides in jQuery mobile for a phoneGap application?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, sliders

I would like to create an app with phonegap and implement this [Whatsapp slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYiOD.jpg). I don't know its actual name. Is it possible to do this in jQuery mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to recreate it precisely, you might think about using Angular and Angular material as the community has already done a good job recreating Android's material design.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

You can use jQuery mobile to create tabs as @Beat mentioned but you might need to tweak heavily to get the precise effect.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. What you are looking for is a "tab" layout. jQuery mobile provides a [navbar widget](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/tabs/) for using. You will also find an example with [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/), if you want to take a look there. It is good for beginners, who want to get in touch with angularjs. Both are requiring phonegap/cordova.